# Reference the previous non-zero row, find the difference and divide by nrows

Tags: r

I must be asking the question terribly because I can't find what I looking for!

I have a large excel file that looks like this for every day of the month:

| Date | Well1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/16 | 10 |
| 1/2/16 | NA |
| 1/3/16 | NA |
| 1/4/16 | NA |
| 1/5/16 | 20 |
| 1/6/16 | NA |
| 1/7/16 | 25 |
| 1/8/16 | NA |
| 1/9/16 | NA |
| 1/10/16 | 35 |
| etc | NA |

I want to make a new column that has the difference between the non-zero rows and divide that by the number of rows between each non zero row. Aiming for something like this:

| Date | Well1 | Adjusted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/16 | 10 | =(20-10)/4 = 2.5 |
| 1/2/16 | NA | 1.25 |
| 1/3/16 | NA | 1.25 |
| 1/4/16 | NA | 1.25 |
| 1/5/16 | 20 | =(25-20)/2= 2.5 |
| 1/6/16 | NA | 2.5 |
| 1/7/16 | 25 | =(35-25)/3 = 3.3 |
| 1/8/16 | NA | 3.3 |
| 1/9/16 | NA | 3.3 |
| 1/10/16 | 35 | etc |
| etc | NA | etc |

I'm thinking I should use `lead` or `lag`, but the thing is that the steps are different between each nonzero row (so I'm not sure how to use n in the lead/lag function). I've used `group_by` so that each month stands alone, as well as attempted `case_when` and `ifelse` Mostly need ideas on translating excel format into a workable R format.

Comment: I get 2.5 for (20-10)/4.  Also, in your input the value was 40 which changed to 35 in expected.

Comment: Thank you, I'll adjust for future readers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R in the same vein as @thelatemail but with transformations all in one expression:

```
nas <- is.na(dat$Well1)
res <- within(dat, {
    Date <- as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%y")
    Adjusted <- (diff(Well1[!nas]) / 
      as.numeric(diff(Date[!nas]), units = "days"))[cumsum(!nas)]
  }
)
```

Data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Date Well1
1/1/16 10
1/2/16 NA
1/3/16 NA
1/4/16 NA
1/5/16 20
1/6/16 NA
1/7/16 25
1/8/16 NA
1/9/16 NA
1/10/16 40", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks- this is super helpful and I was able to adjust it to fit in a couple extra parameters. Question about the last part: [cumsum(!nas)]. Could you explain what's gong on here? Is this part making sure the calculation is only applied to non-NAs?

Comment: No, it is creating a vector the same length as the data.frame `dat` that is a sequence that repeats each element of vector of rates calculated by `(diff(Well1[!nas]) / 
      as.numeric(diff(Date[!nas]), units = "days"))` the appropriate number of times. You should consider upvoting and accepting @thelatemails answer most of the logic I took from his solution below. Out of interest, are you trying automate a well test ?

Comment: Yes, will do! And thanks, that makes sense. 
I'm trying to calculate daily well production (gal per day) for many wells using historical data that was recorded in an unfortunate manner.

Comment: Good luck ! I had to do a similar sort of back allocation calculation for oil wells, you are going about this a very similar way I did (not sure if that's any reassurance lol!)

Answer (score 3):

With some `diff`-ing and repeating of values, you should be able to get there.

```
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, format="%m/%d/%y")
nas <- is.na(dat$Well1)
dat$adj <- with(dat[!nas,],
              diff(Well1) / as.numeric(diff(Date), units="days")
           )[cumsum(!nas)]

#         Date Well1 adj
#1  2016-01-01    10 2.5
#2  2016-01-02    NA 2.5
#3  2016-01-03    NA 2.5
#4  2016-01-04    NA 2.5
#5  2016-01-05    20 2.5
#6  2016-01-06    NA 2.5
#7  2016-01-07    25 5.0
#8  2016-01-08    NA 5.0
#9  2016-01-09    NA 5.0
#10 2016-01-10    40  NA
```

`dat` being used is:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Date Well1
1/1/16 10
1/2/16 NA
1/3/16 NA
1/4/16 NA
1/5/16 20
1/6/16 NA
1/7/16 25
1/8/16 NA
1/9/16 NA
1/10/16 40", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: efficient and eloquent.

Comment: Wow thank you! This works. I like the workaround with pulling out the NAs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this should work

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  #// remove the rows with NA
  na.omit %>%
  # // create a new column with the lead values of Well1
  transmute(Date, Well2 = lead(Well1)) %>% 
  # // join with original data
  right_join(df1 %>%
              mutate(rn = row_number())) %>%
  # // order by the original order 
  arrange(rn) %>%
  # // create a grouping column based on the NA values
  group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(Well1))) %>%
  # // subtract the first element of Well2 with Well1 and divide
  # // by number of rows - n() in the group
  mutate(Adjusted = (first(Well2) - first(Well1))/n()) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp, - Well2)
```